# Why is JSON.parse() not parsing inner array of JSON object?

Tags: javascript, json

Does anyone know why my JSON.parse() is not working correctly? I have tried all the debug tools out there but it's not parsing the array.

My code:

```
console.log(typeof(localStorage.array));
console.log(localStorage.array);
localStorageArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.array);
console.log(localStorageArray);
```

The console:

```
String //line 1
[[{"color":"#000000","teacher":"ELA","tasks":[[{"selection":"homework","name":"HW 1","date":"2020-05-15","time":"16:05","marked":false}]]}]] //line 2
Array(1)
0: Array(1)
0:
color: "#000000"
tasks: Array(0)
length: 0
__proto__: Array(0)
teacher: "ELA"
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0) //The main thing here is that tasks.length == 0
```

Comment: btw, `typeof` in JavaScript doesn't need parentheses, you can use just `console.log( typeof foo )` instead of `console.log( typeof(foo) )`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried out your example with the chrome (Version 81.0.4044.138 (Official Build) (64-bit)) browser and here is the result I am getting.

[Here is a picture of local storage instance that I have stored.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPuIb.png)

[Here is a picture of the 4 steps which you have tried out.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9Ea3.png)

In order to access the tasks array, I have used this command.

```
console.log(localStorageArray[0][0]['tasks']);
```

Here is the full code which is have used to get this result.

```
localStorage.setItem('array','[[{"color":"#000000","teacher":"ELA","tasks":[[{"selection":"homework","name":"HW 1","date":"2020-05-15","time":"16:05","marked":false}]]}]]');

console.log(typeof(localStorage.array));
console.log(localStorage.array);
let localStorageArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.array);
console.log(localStorageArray);
console.log(localStorageArray[0][0]['tasks']); // to access the tasks
```

the console:

```
// second line result
string 


// third line result
[[{"color":"#000000","teacher":"ELA","tasks":[[{"selection":"homework","name":"HW 1","date":"2020-05-15","time":"16:05","marked":false}]]}]] 


 // 4th and 5th line results
0: Array(1)
0:
color: "#000000"
tasks: Array(1)
0: Array(1)
0: {selection: "homework", name: "HW 1", date: "2020-05-15", time: "16:05", marked: false}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
teacher: "ELA"
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0) 


// 6th line result
0: Array(1)
0:
date: "2020-05-15"
marked: false
name: "HW 1"
selection: "homework"
time: "16:05"
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

I have tried out your issue within the HTML file as well. It's working fine for me.

Here is the HTML code which I have tried out.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
  <script >
    localStorage.setItem('array','[[{"color":"#000000","teacher":"ELA","tasks":[[{"selection":"homework","name":"HW 1","date":"2020-05-15","time":"16:05","marked":false}]]}]]');

    console.log(typeof(localStorage.array)); // line 01
    console.log(localStorage.array); // line 02

    let localStorageArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.array);
    console.log(localStorageArray); // line 03
    console.log(localStorageArray[0][0]['tasks']); //line 04
  </script>
  <div>web site working</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the output that I'm getting.

[image]

Comment: Yea that's an issue too

Comment: How do you handle JS in HTML file @Justin?

Comment: @Justin. I have updated the answer. Even I have tried out with the HTML file and script tags, result is same. maybe this issue is because of your browser or it's version I think. Please check this HTML is working for you.

Answer (score 1):

The `localStorage` object has custom property getters/setters that don't behave like normal JavaScript `object` properties.

This is explained here (emphasis mine):

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API
>
> The keys and **the values are always strings** (note that, as with objects, integer keys will be automatically converted to strings).

So when you retrieve a value from a `localStorage` property it will always be returned as a `string`, even if you just set a property with an `object` value.

You should prefer the `getItem` and `setItem` functions instead to avoid this automatic string conversion.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working when I tried, is it maybe because my JSON array is a mess?

Comment: @Justin Possibly! I suggest you repost your question with the code you use to generate the Array in the first place. And please also add a screenshot showing the output in your browser's console because the `Array(1)`-etc output is meaningless without knowing what the output refers to.

Comment: So apparently it's not the issue of the array, but it's because the variable can't really store.

Comment: ``JSON.parse(localStorage.array)`` returns properly, but when I use ``localStorageArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.array)``, that's when the problem happens

Comment: @Justin Where - or how - is `localStorageArray` declared? What happens if you use `var localStorageArray` first? Is it in a closure? What does your JavaScript debugger say?